# jquery Colorbox data scrolling with flot graph

Tags: jquery, colorbox, flot, excanvas

Good Day,
I use colorbox for displaying data in new window.
Everything was good, but I have to display dynamically created data (table with data) and then to draw graph. It was decided to draw data with flot graph jQuery library. 
It was tested in firefox and ie. Graph is good. But when colorbox window is scrolling in ie, graph remains in the same place and other content (table) is scrolling. In firefox scrolling works good.

Colorbox init:

```
$.colorbox({ maxWidth:"95%", 
             maxHeight:"80%", 
             scrolling:true, 
             html: htmlData,  
             onComplete: function(){$.graphCreate();}});

htmlData - <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
<table>......</table>
```

then when colorbox complete - $.graphCreate();

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"),data, {
    series: {
        stack: stack,
    },
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [[1, "Fri, Mar 02 2012"], [2, "Sat, Mar 03 2012"], [3, "Sun, Mar 04 2012"], [4, "Mon, Mar 05 2012"]],
    }
});
```